# Find the first "invalid" character in a string (cleaning phone numbers)

Tags: php, split, phone-number, sanitize

We are updating a system where notes were added to fields containing phone numbers. Using PHP we are trying to clean up the fields and split them into two. One for the phone number and the other for the note. The number is always first and the note after.

We are not overly concerned with the exact format of the resulting phone number. Users can be forced to clean them up when they update their profile. The numbers are US format.

A couple of examples. I imagine there could be other variations:

```
"(123) 456-7890 Betty's cell"
becomes
"(123) 456-7890" and "Betty's cell"

"123-456-7890  Betty's cell
becomes
"123-456-7890" and "Betty's cell"

"456-7890  Betty's cell
becomes
"456-7890" and "Betty's cell"

"456-7890 ext. 123  Betty's cell
becomes
"456-7890 ext. 123" and "Betty's cell"
```

Valid phone number characters would be `"+()-0123456789 "` and to complicate things further we would need to allow for `"ext."` I can sanitize the existing data so all ext. variations are the same. We would be happy to find the position of the first "invalid" character in the string and split it there.

Been searching but can't seem to find anything that fits this situation. Appreciate any suggestions.
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex such as like below;

```
^([\+\(\)\-0-9 ]*)([A-Za-z' ]*)$
```

Group1 result always number and Group2 result will be the name and surname
You can check on https://regex101.com/r/PhEQNH/1/

```
$re = '/^([\+\(\)\-0-9 ]*)([A-Za-z\' ]*)$/';
$str = '123-456-7890  Betty\'s cell
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Thanks Dr. Geek. This works except for the case where there is an extension "ext." in the string. Is it possible to extend the regex to include "ext."?

Comment: With the regex from @trincot and your code I have it working! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a regular expression and `preg_match`:

```
function splitPhoneNotes($s) {
    preg_match("~^([\d() +-]+(?:ext\.[\d() -]+)?)(.*)~", $s, $res);
    return [
        "phone" => trim($res[1]),
        "note" => trim($res[2]) 
    ];
}

// Sample inputs
$arr = [
    "(123) 456-7890 Betty's cell",
    "123-456-7890  Betty's cell",
    "456-7890  Betty's cell",
    "+1 (324) 456-7890 ext. 33 Betty's cell",
];

// Apply the function to each of the inputs
$res = array_map('splitPhoneNotes', $arr);

// Results
print_r($res);
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/IjxB/4)

Comment: Thank you! With the code from Dr Geek and your regex I have it working. Wish I could make two solutions. Both worked. :)

Comment: You're welcome! Once you have enough reputation you can upvote ;-)

Comment: I upvoted you both. I think the message I received was it records but doesn't display or something like that

Comment: I didn't get the upvote. Maybe you clicked it twice: it works like a toggle.

Comment: Tried again but looks like it may be blocking me until my rep is higher.

Comment: Your rep dropped below 15 again, that explains it.